# Перешел с python2.x на python 3.x. Появилась проблема с pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x, pygame

Попытался сделать белое окно, которое закрывается когда нажимаешь на крестик. В итоге появляется белое окно которое не закрывается. В чем проблема?

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([1000, 480])
screen.fill([255, 255, 255])
pygame.display.flip()
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
pygame.quit
```

Comment: сравните с этим примером (2-3 строчки разница). там и пояснения есть к каждой строке https://realpython.com/pygame-a-primer/

Comment: обратите внимание  pygame.quit()

Answer (score 1):

Окно было черным потому что я не использовал pygame.display.flip(), а не закрывалось из за отсутсвия скобо в конце.